# How to grep lines between start and end pattern?

Tags: text-processing, awk, sed, grep

I have a file which is having following content:

```
zdk
aaa
b12
cdn
dke
kdn
```

Input1: `aaa` and `cdn`

Output 1:

```
aaa
b12
cdn
```

Input 2: `zdk` and `dke`

Output 2:

```
zdk
aaa
b12
cdn
dke
```

I could use below commands to achieve:

```
grep -a aaa -A2 file # Output 1
grep -a aaa -A4 file # Output 2
```

But in the file I don't know what is the exact occurrence (position) of end string pattern (file is having 20000 rows)

How can I achieve this?

Comment: I think the other question is too specific to be duplicate of this. Most of the answer from here won't work there, as there are different requirements (by specifying extra new line characters).

Comment: I think here the start and end patterns could be anywhere in the file (no necessary to do with new lines) despite given the specific example, the other asks for the whole lines.

Comment: @kenorb it's still the same idea. The main trick is to use one of the tools that can do `/foo/,/bar/` to define patterns. The specifics of the pattern (being at the end for example) are secondary.

Comment: This answer might also be applicable: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48022994/2026975

Answer (score 82, accepted):

`grep` won't help you here. This is a job better accomplished with `sed` using range expressions:

```
$ sed -n '/aaa/,/cdn/p' file
aaa
b12
cdn
$ sed -n '/zdk/,/dke/p' file
zdk
aaa
b12
cdn
dke
```

`sed -n` suppresses the automatic printing, so that lines are printed just if explicitly asked to. And this happens when the range `/aaa/,/cdn/` happens.

These range expressions are also available in `awk`, where you can say:

```
awk '/zdk/,/dke/' file
```

Of course, all these conditions can be expanded to a more strict regex like `sed -n '/^aaa$/,/^cdn$/p' file` to check that the lines consist on exactly `aaa` and `cdn`, nothing else.

Comment: Wow, I had this same problem and didn't ask. I used 2 instances of `grep -n` and compared the number for my solution.

Comment: @KipK range expressions are such a useful tool for these kind of problems : ) You can also use `awk` and some flags, but the basic case is quite straight forward with this.

Comment: @Fedorqui, i getting some problem if the search pattern contains xmls. like, I need to search starting with <ns0:abcd xmlns=""> , getting the resull. But it is showing <abcd xmlns=""> also. I have tried sed -n '/\<ns0\:abcd xmlns\=\"\"\>/,/\<ns0\:abcd\>/p file

Comment: @Spike maybe you should edit your question to show this sample file. To me, `sed -n '/^<ns0:abcd xmlns="">$/,/dke/p' file` works fine. Note I added `^` and `$` to match the string exactly. Note you can also check my answer in [How to select lines between two marker patterns which may occur multiple times with awk/sed](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17988834/1983854).

Comment: is it shortest match ?

Comment: @MukulAnand please provide an example so we can cross check

Comment: Any way how to *not* print the start and end pattern themselves (except for using head and tail)?

Comment: @Marki see https://stackoverflow.com/q/38972736/1983854

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't seem easy to use non-greedy matching of the end range?

Comment: I need to get something like this in AWK: `cat ~/.aws/config | sed -n '/'"$AWS_PROFILE"'/,/^\[/p'`. So it should be between the starting pattern and next unknown word that is between the square brackets. AWK does not print it as expected `cat ~/.aws/config | awk '/\['"$AWS_PROFILE"'\]/,/^\[/'`

Answer (score 4):

It can be done by `sed`

```
sed -n '
    /^aaa$/,/^cdn$/w output1
    /^zdk$/,/^dke$/w output2
    ' file
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is `grep` command:

```
grep -o "aaa.*cdn" <(paste -sd_ file) | tr '_' '\n'
```

You can achieve multiline match in `grep`, but you need to use perl-regexp for `grep` (`-P` - which is not supported on every platform, like OS X), so as workaround we're replacing new lines with `_` character and after `grep`, we're changing them back.

Alternatively you can use [`pcregrep`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/152708/55075) which supports multi-line patterns (`-M`).

Or use `ex`:

```
ex +"/aaa/,/cdn/p" -scq! file
```