# grab from a text file a range using two variables as the beginning and end parameters

Tags: text-processing, grep, variable

I'm trying to grab a specific range of lines from a text file using grep; the line range needs to be identified by two variables. so far, I've been trying to do it using the wildcard '*' examples of failed attempts include:
(I can see why the first two shouldn't work)

```
grep "$Var1"*"$Var2" file.txt     
grep "$Var1*$Var2" file.txt
echo "$Var1*$Var2" | grep file.txt
```

Comment: This has been asked too many times... Basically, you want to know [How to grep lines between start and end pattern?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/236751) and, if you decide to use `sed` for that, [How can I use variables when doing a sed?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/69112) more specifically [How to ensure that string interpolated into `sed` substitution escapes all metachars?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/129059)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`grep` is not designed to search patterns over multiple lines. There are other tools better suited for this task: `awk` and `sed`.

Since you are using variables to hold the patterns things can get tricky. Please try first with hardcoded patterns. If you got that right then try to replace the hardcoded patterns with variables.

---

Using `awk`:

```
awk '/'"$Var1"'/,/'"$Var2"'/' file.txt
```

The same command with hardcoded patterns to explain the concept:

```
awk '/pattern1/,/pattern2/' file.txt
```

Explanation:

- `/pattern1/,/pattern2/` is a range. the range begins at the line matching `pattern1` and ends at the line matching `pattern2`.
- by default `awk` only prints lines that are in the range.

Learn more about `awk`: http://www.catonmat.net/blog/awk-one-liners-explained-part-one/

---

Using `sed`:

```
sed -n '/'"$Var1"'/,/'"$Var2"'/ p' file.txt
```

The same command with hardcoded patterns to explain the concept:

```
sed -n '/pattern1/,/pattern2/ p' file.txt
```

Explanation:

- `-n` makes sed to print lines only if told.
- `/pattern1/,/pattern2/` is a range. the range begins at the line matching `pattern1` and ends at the line matching `pattern2`. for every line in that range the following commands are executed.
- the `p` at the end tells `sed` to print lines.

Learn more about `sed`: http://www.catonmat.net/blog/sed-one-liners-explained-part-one/

---

If you really have to use `grep` then you can use `-P` to tell `grep` to use the perl regular expression engine. The man page has this to say about that feature:

> Interpret the pattern as a  Perl-compatible  regular  expression (PCRE). This  is  highly  experimental and grep -P may warn of unimplemented features.