# Grep/sed/awk solution to excludes lines between two search keywords

Tags: text-processing, awk, sed, grep

I see there are ways to print lines between two search patterns, as explained here [How to grep lines between start and end pattern?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/236751/how-to-grep-lines-between-start-and-end-pattern)

```
sed -n '/aaa/,/cdn/p' file
awk '/test1/,/test2/'
```

I need negation of the above, and finding it hard to get the correct command/solution using the standard unix commands grep/sed/awk.

`grep -v` excludes the lines matching the words, but not all the line between two specific regexs.

Any hints?

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
sed '/aaa/,/cdn/d' file
```

or

```
awk '/test1/,/test2/{next} {print}'
```

or (more compactly)

```
awk '/test1/,/test2/{next} 1'
```

which prints each record (line) by default, **unless** it matches `/test1/,/test2/` in which case it skips to the *next* record.

Comment: tried the `awk` solution.. work perfectly. so the {next} block does what exactly? please elaborate

Comment: @mtk I have added a brief explanation of the awk command

Comment: @mtk The `{next}` block is needed to work around a limitation / design bug in `awk` -- the fact the range (`/pat1/,/pat2`) is not a real expression, and cannot be negated or used in a conditional. That was fixed in `perl`, where you can do the obvious: `perl -ne 'print unless /test1/../test2/'`

Comment: @mtk the range operator **can** be negated in `sed`, so you could also write `sed -n '/pat1/,/pat2/!p'`.