# How do I print the last sequence of lines between a start and an end pattern?

Tags: text-processing, awk, sed, grep, pattern-matching

Answers to this question:

[How to grep lines between start and end pattern?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/236751/34868)

are not concerned with multiple sequences of lines which fall between the match patterns. Thus, for example, `sed -n '/startpattern_here/,/endpattern_here/p'` will print several sequences of lines which lie between occurrences of these patterns.

However, suppose I want to only print the *last* such sequences within a file. Can I do this with sed? If not, I guess probably awk? Something else?

Notes:

- You may assume that these sequences are non-overlapping.
- The starting and ending pattern lines *should* be included in the output.
- Answers making assumptions of lower-complexity patterns are also valid (although not optimal).

Comment: Would the start and end patterns be full regular expressions? If not, could they contain RegExp special characters?

Comment: @AdminBee: If you have a decent answer making the assumption they're not full-on regular expressions - that's already an interesting answer.

Comment: [edit] your question to include a MCVE with concise, testable sample input and expected output plus what you've tried to far so we can best help you. Include your requirements for what to do if the start or end "pattern" doesn't exist in your input.

Comment: @EdMorton: Not necessary... 5 people have already gotten enough information to provide interesting answers.

Comment: I think the point detected by @AdminBee in his answer not totally defined yet. What should happen if there is a last start pattern but no pairing end pattern? The proposed sed you give us would give one thing as a result, but the 2nd bullet point seems to contradict it. Could you please clarify that point?

Comment: @einpoklum I'm glad you find the answers interesting but they're all making different assumptions about what you actually want in any but the the sunny-day cases so I disagree that posting a MCVE and covering your rainy day requirements isn't necessary. See [ask].

Answer (score 7):

This might work, assuming you want a full regular expression test:

```
awk '/startpattern_here/ {buf="";f=1}
     f{buf=buf $0 "\n"}
     /endpattern_here/ {f=0; lastcomplete=buf}
     END{printf("%s",lastcomplete)}' file.txt
```

This will ensure that only complete start-stop-patterns will be printed.

Test case:

```
irrelevant
irrelevant
irrelevant
startpattern_here
relevant_but_dont_show_1
relevant_but_dont_show_1
relevant_but_dont_show_1
endpattern_here

irrelevant
irrelevant
 
startpattern_here
relevant_but_dont_show_2
relevant_but_dont_show_2
relevant_but_dont_show_2
endpattern_here

irrelevant
irrelevant

startpattern_here
relevant_and_show
relevant_and_show
relevant_and_show
endpattern_here

irrelevant
startpattern_here
incomplete_dont_show
```

Result:

```
startpattern_here
relevant_and_show
relevant_and_show
relevant_and_show
endpattern_here
```

**Note** If you want to suppress the output of the start and end patterns, just swap the rules `/startpattern_here/ { ... }` and `/endpattern_here/ { ... }`, i.e. place the "end pattern" rule first, and the "start pattern" rule just before the `END` rule.

Answer (score 6):

Combination of tac and awk

```bsh
tac file \
| awk '
   !p && /endpattern_here/   {p = 1}
    p                        {print}
    p && /startpattern_here/ {exit}
' \
| tac
```

Comment: Thanks for the sed fix - but that should be a comment on my answer... also, given that we can do this with sed - is there a benefit to tac+awk+tac? Allowing myself an edit..., and +1

Comment: Yes, should have been a comment. sed vs awk: I would be very surprised if there was any difference in performance, and IMO awk is far more flexible and readable.

Comment: This will print from the last `End` to the start of the file if no `Start` is found (thus: an incomplete section). Awk is able to correct that.

Comment: Wait... what if there's an extra occurrence of the end pattern after the last pair of start-then-end patterns? I think this will get it wrong.

Comment: Indeed this would fetch `startpattern \ntext\n endpattern \ntext\n endpattern` from the end. To solve this, you can add at the end  `| awk '{print} /endpattern_here/{exit}'`

Answer (score 6):

With [Ex](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/ex.html) (a POSIX editor) that is quite simple:

```
printf '%s\n' 1 '?END?' '?START?,.p' | ex -s file
```

- `1` goes to the first line of the file. This is necessary in case `END` is the last line of the file.
- `?END?` seeks backward (wrapping around the end-of-file) for the `END`, thus finding its last occurrence in the file.
- `?START?,.p` prints all from the previous `START` up to the current address.

Below an example with here-docs instead of `printf`, just for diversity.

```
$ cat file
zdk
START
b12
END
kdn
START
000
111
END
START
ddd
```

```
$ ex -s file <<EOF
> 1
> ?END?
> ?START?,.p
> EOF
START
000
111
END
```

Comment: Ahh... so it works with ex - that's good to know

Comment: @steeldriver Yeah, but the `1` was missing in the previous version. However, Ed prints the line with `1`, that is why it does not work with Ed.

Comment: It is also possible to do it in ed: `printf '%s\n' '1;#' '?END?;#' '?START?;/END/p' | ed -s file`. A `;#` sets the current line. A `?END?` finds the last `END` in the file and then the `START - END` range gets printed by the next command. The first `1;#` may be omitted if it is the first command of the `ed` script. Otherwise, it should be used for reliability. @steeldriver

Comment: With `ed` we can do as: `?START?;/END/p` as the last line is the default current line when a file is first read in.

Comment: Why do I need the printf? Wouldn't `echo -e "1 ?START?,?END?p\n"` work?

Comment: @einpoklum You could use echo, but [it fails in some edge cases and is not much portable](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/65803/why-is-printf-better-than-echo). In my system, that would be `echo -e '1\n?START?,?END?p'`

Comment: Nice @Quasímodo , I wouldve come up with something similar. Funny how often ed/ex work so well :)

Comment: @einpoklum Using `?start?,?end?p` could lead to errors. Compare: `printf '%s\n' '?^10?;?^14?p' | ed -s <(seq 15)` which prints the intended lines with: `printf '%s\n' '?^10?;?^1?p' | ed -s <(seq 15)` which will fail (as the **previous** line that start with a `1` is before the start line and ranges where the start is after the end are not allowed). In short: An ending `?end?` doesn't mean **next match**.

Answer (score 4):

It seems I can just use `tac`:

```
tac | sed -n '/endpattern_here/,/startpattern_here/ {p; /startpattern_here/q;}' | tac
```

Thanks goes to @glenn jackman and @Quasimodo for helping me get my sed invocation right.

Comment: `tac file | sed -n '/END/,/START/p;/START/q' | tac`

Comment: @Quasímodo: Thanks :-)

Comment: @Quasímodo, unless there's a start pattern *after* the last complete block, as demonstrated in AdminBee's solution.

Comment: @glennjackman In that case, the desired output is not well defined: the sed in OP question would agree with my output, but it indeed would lack `END`.

Comment: This will print from the last `End` to the start of the file if no `Start` is found.

Answer (score 2):

one way would be to simply store each set, override it with the next one, and print whichever set you have kept once you get to the end:

```
awk '{ 
        if(/startpattern_here/){
            a=1; 
            lines=$0; 
            next
        } 
        if(a){
            lines=lines"\n"$0
        } 
        if(/end_pattern/){
            a=0
        }
    } 
    END{
        print lines
    }' file
```

For example, using this test file:

```
startpattern_here
line 1
line 2
line 3
end_pattern
startpattern_here
line 1b
line 2b
line 3b
end_pattern
startpattern_here
line 1c
line 2c
line 3c
end_pattern
```

I get:

```
$ awk '{ if(/startpattern_here/){a=1; lines=$0; next} if(a){lines=lines"\n"$0} if(/end_pattern/){a=0}} END{print lines}' file
startpattern_here
line 1c
line 2c
line 3c
end_pattern
```

Comment: Isn't this about the same as @AdminBee's solution?

Comment: @einpoklum pretty much, yes. I posted mine about 5 minutes before. We must have been writing it at the same time. Great minds... :P

Comment: @einpoklum Yeah, I saw the notification about an existing answer when I was about to post mine, and to my surprise it turned out they are very similar in their approach (then again, terdon and I had similar correlations already when commenting on posts ...)

Comment: This will print the last incomplete section (that have an start but not and end) if it exists.

Answer (score 2):

- You can `grep` out the last range using PCRE flavor of grep in slurp mode.

  ```
  grep -zoP '(?ms).*\K^start.*?\nend[^\n]*' file | tr '\0' '\n'
  ```
- We use the range operator in `awk` to store and re store once we start a new range. Assuming there is no dangling start pattern line in the vicinity of eof.

  ```
  awk '
    /^start/,/^end/ {
      t = (/^start/ ? "" : t ORS) $0
    }
    END { print t }
  ' file
  ```
- Here we use the `tac` file to reverse it and then the `m??` operator in Perl which matches just once.

  ```
  < file tac \
  | perl -lne 'print if m?end? .. m?start?' \
  | tac;
  ```
- Other alternatives

  ```
  < file sed -ne '/start/=;/end/='  \
  | sed -ne 'N;s/\n/,/;$s/$/p/p' \
  | sed -nf - file
  ```

  ```
  < file \
  tac | sed -e '/start/q' |
  tac | sed -e '/end/q'
  ```

  ```
  sed -e '
    /start/,/end/H
    /start/h;g;$q;d
  ' file
  ```

Comment: The use of `-P` (PCRE) with `-z` is said to be experimental in GNU grep manual. I don't believe that this is a good idea.

Answer (score 2):

Most answers here either

1. fail to handle the case where either the start or the end pattern does not exist, or where a line matches both the start and the end pattern.
2. store whole ranges of lines in the memory (unscalable).
3. use some editor like `ed` or `ex` which first loads the whole file in the memory.

For the case where the input file is a regular/seekable file (not pipe input), a dumb-simple solution which just gets the last offsets where the start and end patterns matched, and then seeks+reads from there to  may be a better idea.

```
LC_ALL=C awk -v SP=start_pattern -v EP=end_pattern '
   {o+=length+1}
   $0~SP, q=($0~EP) { if(!p) p=o-length; if(q){ l=o+1-(s=p); p=0 } }
   END { if(s && l) system("tail -c +"s" "FILENAME" | head -c "l) }
' file
```

For the case where the input is from a pipe, you can use a simple pattern range and juggle two temporary files, using `close(filename)` to rewind them:

```
... | awk -v SP=start_pattern -v EP=end_pattern -v tmp="$(mktemp)" -v out="$(mktemp)" '
  $0~SP, q=($0~EP){
     print > tmp; if(q){ close(tmp); t=tmp; tmp=out; out=t; }
  }
  END { if(t) system("cat "out); system("rm -f " out " "tmp) }
'
```

Since any solution will have to parse the whole file before printing anyway (otherwise there's no way to know that it had printed the *last* range), it makes more sense not to print anything for a file where only the *start* pattern was found. This is obviously a discutable change from the behaviour of the range operator in sed, awk or perl.

Examples:

```
seq 1 107 > file
LC_ALL=C awk -v SP=9 -v EP=1 '
   {o+=length+1}
   $0~SP, q=($0~EP) { if(!p) p=o-length; if(q){ l=o+1-(s=p); p=0 } }
   END { if(s && l) system("tail -c +"s" "FILENAME" | head -c "l) }
' file
92
...
100

seq 1 107 | awk -v SP=9 -v EP=1 -v tmp="$(mktemp)" -v out="$(mktemp)" '
  $0~SP, q=($0~EP){
     print > tmp; if(q){ close(tmp); t=tmp; tmp=out; out=t; }
  }
  END { if(t) system("cat "out); system("rm -f " out " "tmp) }
'
92
...
100
```

Comment: Very efficient solution. The combination head-tail is very fast. As you say, for a complete solution, we have to search all the file, and an interesting attempt would be, for this part, one grep instead of awk, and a few lines of code to parse its output and decide the start-end lines, if any.

Answer (score 1):

```
$ seq 20 > file
$ awk '/5/{rec=""; f=1} f{rec=rec $0 ORS; if (/8/) f=0} END{if (!f) printf "%s", rec}' file
15
16
17
18
```

Comment: The OP didn't specify if that can happen, but if there is an "incomplete" pattern (say, `seq 16 > file`), your approach would output nothing (as `f=1` would still be set by the start pattern rule) ...

Comment: Right, I asked the OP to specify their requirements for cases like that but they said it's "not necessary" so idk if that can happen or not and if it can what they want to do.

Answer (score 1):

```
 perl -ne '$x = (/startpattern/../endpattern/ ? $x . $_ : ""); $y=$x if $x and /endpattern/; END { print $y }'
```

Or, more readably (i.e. not on one line):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -n

# save a set; could be incomplete
$x = /startpattern/../endpattern/
        ?   $x . $_
        :   ""
    ;

# save last complete set seen
if ($x and /endpattern/) {
    $y = $x;
}

# print last complete set seen, ignoring any incomplete sets that may have come after
END {
    print $y;
}
```

Which you run as `perl ./script < inputfile`

Answer (score 1):

Some possible solutions:

[sed](/questions/tagged/sed): `sed -z 's/.*\(StartPattern.*EndPattern[^\n]*\n\).*/\1\n/' file`
[ed](/questions/tagged/ed) : `printf '%s\n' '1;kx' '?^End?;kx' "?^Start?;'xp" | ed -s file`
[ex](/questions/tagged/ex) : `printf '%s\n' '1' '?^End?' "?^Start?,.p" | ex file`
[awk](/questions/tagged/awk): `awk '/^Start/{s=1;section=""}`
                  `s{section=section $0 ORS}`
             `/^End/{complete=section;s=0}`
                `END{printf ("%s",complete)}'          file`
[tac](/questions/tagged/tac): `tac file | sed -n '/^End/,/^Start/{p;/^Start/q}' | tac`

---

## regex sed

You can match the last occurrence of a pattern between `start` and `end` with a regex like:

```
.*START.*END.*
```

Then, you can extract the range including the delimiters with a parentheses.

```
.*\(START.*END\).*
```

That will work in sed (as it may use the replace s///) but require GNU sed to make the whole file one string (using the -z option):

```
sed -z 's/.*\(StartPattern.*EndPattern[^\n]*\n\).*/\1\n/' file
```

## ed

It is possible to search backwards in `ed` with `?regex?`. So, we can search backwards for `EndPattern` (to ensure the pattern is complete and we are at the last one) and then search also backward to the previous `StartPattern`.

`printf '%s\n' '?^End?;kx' '?^Start?;kx' '.;/End/p' | ed -s file`

The `;kx` is used to avoid that ed prints the selected line.

That would fail if the last line is `End`, to avoid that, start on the first line and search backward for `End`.

And, since the limits are being marked, we can use a simpler range:

`printf '%s\n' '1;ky' '?^End?;ky' '?^Start?;kx' "'x;'yp" | ed -s file`

Or,

`printf '%s\n' '1;kx' '?^End?;kx' "?^Start?;'xp" | ed -s file`

That is assuming that at least one complete section of `Start` -- `End` exists. If there is none, the script will fail.

I have seen several uses of `?Start?,?End?`. That may fail in several ways because it doesn't mean "find the **next** `End` after what was found by `Start`. Compare:

````
$ printf '%s\n' 1 '?START?,?END?p' | ex -s <(printf '%s\n' 111 START 222 END 333 END 444)

START
222
END
333
END


$ printf '%s\n' 1 '?START?,/END/p' | ex -s <(printf '%s\n' 111 START 222 END 333 END 444)

START
222
END


# ex
The command from `ed` could be simplified to work in `ex`:

```printf '%s\n' '1' '?^End?' '?^Start?,.p' | ex file```


# awk
We can store each complete section `Start` to `End` in one variable and print it at the end.
````

awk '
/^Start/{s=1;section=""}          # If there is an start, mark a section.
s{section=section $0 ORS}  # if inside a section, capture all lines.
/^End/{complete=section;s=0}    # If a section ends, unmark it but store.
END{printf ("%s",complete)}'    file # Print a complete section (if one existed).

````
# tac
We can reverse the whole file (line by line) and then print only the **first** section that starts at `End` and ends at `Start`. Then reverse again:

```tac file | sed -n '/^End/,/^Start/{p;/^Start/q}' | tac```

The `/^Start/q` exists sed to ensure that only the first section is printed.

Note that this will print everything from the last `End` to the start of the file if there is no `Start` to be found (instead of just not printing).


### test file
Tested with (at least) this file (and others):
````

$ cat file3
Don't print 1
Don't print 2
Don't print 3
StartPattern_here-1
Inside Pattern but Don't print 1-1
Inside Pattern but Don't print 1-2
Inside Pattern but Don't print 1-3
EndPattern_here-1

Lines between 1 and 2 - 1
Lines between 1 and 2 - 2
Lines between 1 and 2 - 3

StartPattern_here-2
Inside Pattern but Don't print 2-1
Inside Pattern but Don't print 2-2
Inside Pattern but Don't print 2-3
EndPattern_here-2

Lines between 2 and 3 - 1
Lines between 2 and 3 - 2
Lines between 2 and 3 - 3

StartPattern_here-3
Inside Pattern, Please Do print 3-1
Inside Pattern, Please Do print 3-2
Inside Pattern, Please Do print 3-3
EndPattern_here-3

Lines between 3 and 4 - 1
Lines between 3 and 4 - 2
Lines between 3 and 4 - 3

StartPattern_here-4
This section has an start
but not an end, thus,
incomplete.
Lines between 4 and $ - 1
Lines between 4 and $ - 2
Lines between 4 and $ - 3

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution trying to handle all cases, including no printing for no block found, and be efficient in memory and execution time. There is no writing line by line in this solution, no processing of every line and no lines buffering.

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
    
sp="startpattern_here"
ep="endpattern_here"
f="file"
    
range=$(tac "$f" | grep -n "$sp\|$ep" | awk -F: -v sp="$sp" -v ep="$ep"\
        '$2 ~ sp && prev ~ ep {s=$1; print s,e; exit} {prev=$2; e=$1}')
    
if [[ "$range" ]]; then
    # echo "Counting from the end => start: ${range% *} end: ${range#* }"
    tail -n "${range% *}" "$f" | head -n "${range#* }"
else
    echo "No blocks found" 1>&2
fi
```

Explanation and example:

```
> cat file
startpattern_here
text
endpattern_here
startpattern_here
text
startpattern_here
42
endpattern_here
text
endpattern_here
```

In the worst case scenario, we have to search the whole file for a complete answer, so we use the fast `grep` for that. We start searching from the end, so it will get something like this:

```
1:endpattern_here
3:endpattern_here
5:startpattern_here
7:startpattern_here
8:endpattern_here
10:startpattern_here
```

which is piped to `awk` to decide if there is a valid last block or not. Note that here `awk` is being used for simple programming, not for the actual text processing. For a large input, `grep` is faster than searching the file with `awk` or even more, writing line by line with `awk` or `sed`.

Also, in case a block between patterns is detected quickly close at the end, `awk` is exiting and closing its pipe, so the previous sequence is also exiting, without searching the whole file.

This way, we get the range, counting from the end, and finally `tail` and `head` seek() to those line numbers and "cat" the content.  In case of empty range, there is no standard output.

```
startpattern_here
42
endpattern_here
```

Answer (score 0):

**Fast and simple sed-only solution**. Most other solutions are either wasting resources by double-tac-ing, or even worse, loading whole input into memory at once, or doing multiple pass processing in some way.

This processes text line-by-line, so we only requires memory for one copy of matched block, and we don't fork and exec other stuff which would do even more extra processing. As a bonus, it is quite readable and understandable (well, as far as any sed script can be).

Instead of your: `sed -n '/startpattern_here/,/endpattern_here/p'` you do this:

```
sed -n '/startpattern_here/,/endpattern_here/H; /startpattern_here/h; ${g;p}'
```

Explanation (note: anything after `;` is independent of previous commands, unless grouped with `{` and `}`):

- first part  `/startpattern_here/,/endpattern_here/H` is mostly similar to one in your question, but instead of outright printing to stdout everything found between start and end patterns, it instead appends that text to "hold space" (`H`).
- `/startpattern_here/h` notices when NEW match starts, and erases previous hold space by overwriting it (`h`) with current pattern space. Note that next line in file will of course start executing all of our commands from scratch, which will keep appending to hold space (see above point) - result being that we will always keep in hold space only last matched block.
- `${g;p}` - `$` address matches only on last line in file, so anything between `{` and `}` is executed only when we're finished with processing file. Here we simply print content of hold space (by `g` - copying hold space to pattern space, and `p` - printing pattern space)

for example, to get last Debian package basic info:

```
% sed -n '/^Package/,/^Section/H; /^Package/h; ${g;p}' /var/lib/dpkg/status

Package: zsh-common
Status: install ok installed
Priority: optional
Section: shells
```

Comment: Wouldn't this script fail if the start pattern were found after the last occurrence of the end pattern?

Comment: @einpoklum It would behave **in the same way as your original sed script would** (with the obvious exception from requirement of only printing *last* result instead of *all* of them). Note that even your original sed `/start/,/end/p` will print lines from start pattern until end pattern **or** until end of file occurs, whichever happens first. See EdMorton comments to your question if that is not what you actually want, and edit question to better define problem.