# How to show dmesg logs within a certain timeframe?

Tags: bash, fedora

In Fedora 29 (which I'm forced to use), `dmesg` lacks the options `--since` and `--until` like `journalctl` does.

```bash
journalctl --since "2022-12-20 09:00:00" --until "2022-12-20 10:00:00"
```

How `dmesg` logs within `9AM` to `10AM` of `Dec 20` can be filtered to be shown?

Comment: Did you check the man page of `dmesg`? https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/dmesg.1.html

Comment: Yes, it lacks the options since and until in the version I have (2.32.1)

Comment: @Damon do you have `--time-format` option in your dmesg version? It should be useful to know if you do it to can run this command and parse it correctly: `sudo dmesg --time-format 'ctime'`

Comment: `journalctl` is also able to show `dmesg` messages by using `sudo journalctl -k` (but given that you say that `journalctl` does not have the options `--since` and `--until` then this is not so useful)

Comment: Actually, my wording was confusing, journalctl has those options under my system. I will check -k tomorrow to see if I get the oom-kill log which is the one I care about.
My dmesg also has --time-format as an option.
I noticed I can use `date -d $(dmesg -T --time-format iso | grep -w "oom-kill" | cut -d ',' -f 1) +%s` to get the time of the log (in seconds from epoch) for doing comparison.

Comment: @Damon then you can use `sudo journalctl -k --since "2022-12-20 09:00:00" --until "2022-12-20 10:00:00" without having to parse `dmesg`. Hope that helps!
`

Comment: `journalctl -k` gives me this:
`-- Logs begin at Tue 2019-01-29 17:48:05 PST, end at Thu 2022-12-22 09:20:36 PST. --
-- No entries --`

Comment: @Damon Are you running with `sudo`? I also have that output if I do not use `sudo`

Comment: @Edgar with or without sudo, it's the same behavior. (I'm logged in as root)

Comment: @Edgar, actually, your suggestion works! I was using a lxc and running `dmesg` on the container. `dmesg` works in there since it shows the identical logs as physical host does. But `journalctl` doesn't show any logs on the container, only the physical host! Thank you!

Comment: @Damon that explains why `journalctl` did not work. It'd be interesting if `journalctl` can/could show logs from  containers such as `lxc`,`docker`,`podman` (maybe `journalctl` can get logs from containers created by `systemd-nspawn`). I will search about that :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### The `--time-format` long option for `dmesg` is a possibility using the **iso** format:

***(note the `T` and no space between the date and the time, due to the iso format)***

[The sed only works](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/236754/549100) if you have a line with `2022-12-12T09` and a line with `2022-12-12T10` in your logs.

```
$ sudo dmesg --time-format=iso | sed -n '/2022-12-12T09/,/2022-12-12T10/p'
```

### You could alternatively do something like this to add more specificity to the time range (*here, we are grabbing only the specified minutes in the range*):

In this one, you'd also need a line with `2022-12-12T09:16` and a line with `2022-12-12T09:24` in your logs.

```
$ sudo dmesg --time-format=iso | sed -n '/2022-12-12T09:16/,/2022-12-12T09:24/p'
```

From the [manpage](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/dmesg.1.html)

> **--time-format** format
> Print  timestamps  using  the given format, which can be ctime, reltime, delta or iso.  The first three formats are aliases of the
> time-format-specific options.  The iso format is a dmesg implementation of the ISO-8601 timestamp format.
> The purpose of this format is to make the comparing of
> timestamps between two systems, and any other parsing, easy.  The definition
> of the iso timestamp is: YYYY-MM-DDHH:MM:SS,<-+>.
>
> The iso format has the same issue as ctime: the time may be
> inaccurate when a system is suspended and resumed.

Comment: I'm not sure what you are trying to achieve with sed! How do you filter logs only between 9 AM to 10 AM? For example a log that has timestamp 2022-12-12T09:26:19 should be shown.
Consider 9 and 10 are arbitrary. This can be between any two dates with possibly different days and hours.

Comment: I was able to test it. You are basically printing all lines between the two. Did it work for you?

Comment: For me, it doesn't show any logs between the specified range, although I know there are logs with timestamp in that range.

Comment: @Damon, updated answer to clarify

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a little script to collect logs from a range

```
while read line; do
        d=$(echo $line | cut -d ',' -f 1)
        if [[ $line =~ ^[[:digit:]] ]] && [[ `date -d "$d" +%s` > `date --date="2 hours ago" +%s` ]]
        then
                echo $line
        fi
done < <(dmesg -T --time-format iso)
```

This will only show logs `since` 2 hours ago. `until` can be scripted using the same logic and a different math.
The only problem is, it's slower than dmesg itself.

Comment: Indeed, [Bash `while read` loop extremely slow compared to `cat`, why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13762625/bash-while-read-loop-extremely-slow-compared-to-cat-why) but this could probably be refactored to use Awk, especially if your date stamps are in a sane machine-readable format.

Comment: I found out even a worse problem! dmesg -T doesn't report the timestamp accurately! It's 12 minutes behind and it could be days according to this: https://serverfault.com/questions/576139/dmesg-time-vs-system-time-time-isnt-correct
I will try other solution, thank you all for helping me.